# Python: Finding a value in 1 list and finding that corresponding index in another list

Tags: python

My function is given a 'to_find_value' then I have 2 lists which are the same in length and index values. Once I find the index value in list 1 that 'to_find_value' is in, I want to take that index of list 2 and return the value found at list 2.

Ex:

```
function_name('tree', ['bush', 'tree', 'shrub'], ['red', 'green', 'yellow'])
'green'
```

So in the above function I was given tree, and I found it at index 1 in list 1 so then I go to index 1 in list 2 and return the value at that index

This is what I have started so far but I am unsure how to format an 'unknown' index:

```
for plant in plant_data:  
    if plant in list1:  
    list1[?] == list2[?]  
return list2[?}
```

*The '?' represents the part I'm unsure about

Comment: You will either have to keep track of the index while you iterate along `plant_data` (-> read about `enumerate`), or iterate along the lists together (-> read about `zip`).

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
def f(a,b,c):
    return c[b.index(a)]
```

Then call it like:

```
print(f('tree', ['bush', 'tree', 'shrub'], ['red', 'green', 'yellow']))
```

Output is:

```
green
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the index method:

```
return list2[list1.index(plant)]
```

Comment: Isn't this copying mine?

Comment: Apologies. It appears I was 19 seconds too slow.

Comment: @U9-Forward it's not. Racing to answer tutorial-grade basic questions has the risk of arriving at the same simple conclusion.

Comment: @AndrasDeak That's true, replication don't matter :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use index method for list

```
>>> ["foo", "bar", "baz"].index("bar")
1
```

This will return the index of the first occurrence

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the function your looking for is index, which will return the index of the element in the list if it exists (and throw a value error if it doesn't). You can do something like this:

```
list2[list1.index("tree")]
```

list1.index("tree") will return 1, which you can then use to access list2.

Comment: As specified in your posted function call, you pass lists into your function.  Their origin is immaterial after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `enumerate` function to keep track of the index and the item at the same time:

```
for idx, plant in enumerate(plant_data):
    if plant in list1:
        list1[idx] = list2[idx]
```